# Como a declaração de uma classe no Python lida com o escopo externo?

Tags: python, característica-linguagem, cpython

Para exemplificar, vamos considerar essa declaração de classe:

```py
x = 1

class Foo:
    a = x
    b = [x]
    c = [x for _ in range(1)]

print(f'x = {x}')  # x = 1
print(f'Foo.a = {Foo.a}')  # Foo.a = 1
print(f'Foo.b = {Foo.b}')  # Foo.b = [1]
print(f'Foo.c = {Foo.c}')  # Foo.c = [1]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/YA5rCI) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/MammothEverlastingMysql)</sup>

O que mostra que durante a declaração da classe o valor de `x` é buscado no escopo global, dado que no escopo da classe não está definido. Porém, se definirmos um valor para `x` na classe a saída muda:

```py
x = 1

class Foo:
    x = 2
    a = x
    b = [x]
    c = [x for _ in range(1)]

print(f'x = {x}')  # x = 1
print(f'Foo.a = {Foo.a}')  # Foo.a = 2
print(f'Foo.b = {Foo.b}')  # Foo.b = [2]
print(f'Foo.c = {Foo.c}')  # Foo.c = [1]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/pHO0Si) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/ShrillSpatialMachinelanguage)</sup>

Os valores de `Foo.a` e `Foo.b` passam a utilizar o valor de `Foo.x`, mas o valor de `Foo.c` continua considerando o `x` global.

Esse comportamento se dá porque em `Foo.c` é utilizado a *list comprehension*? Como, de fato, o interpretador gerencia o escopo durante a declaração de uma classe?

Answer (score 1):

Que loucura! Achei essa [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198906/list-comprehension-rebinds-names-even-after-scope-of-comprehension-is-this-righ) falando disso, o nome é **List Comprehensions Leak**. O prório Guido explica [aqui](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/from-list-comprehensions-to-generator.html).

Comportamentos diferentes em python **2** e **3** (baseado no post do Guido):

```py
x = 42
a = [x for x in (1, 2, 3)]
print(x) # imprime 3 no py2 e 42 no py3
```

Para você acessar o `x` local não pode usar list comprehension,
acho que fizeram isso para evitar o tal ***leak***

```py
x = 111

class Foo:
    x = 222
    a = x
    b = [x]

    c = [x for _ in range(1)]

    d = []
    for _ in range(1):
        d.append(x)

print(f'x = {x}')  # x = 111
print(f'Foo.a = {Foo.a}')  # Foo.a = 222
print(f'Foo.b = {Foo.b}')  # Foo.b = [222]
print(f'Foo.c = {Foo.c}')  # Foo.c = [111]
print(f'Foo.d = {Foo.d}')  # Foo.c = [222]
```